# ANN : a posteriori variable selection based on weights

Tags: neural-network, feature-selection

I have trained a vanilla NN, with m explanatory variables and p neurons in the first layer. Hence I have a m x p matrice of weight of the first layer.

I have standardised my input variables. So I expect the weights to be comparable in some ways.

The number of my variable m is a bit too high for practical reasons. So I'd like to reduce it.

Reading my weight matrice by line (weight of a variable trough different neurons) wouldn't make any sense.

Reading this matrix by columns, however, allows to see the weight of different variables for a given neuron. So for a given neuron it allows to compare variables weigths (because they are standardised) and highlight which variable are not so important in terms of weights. For practical purpose I consider a variable as not important if the absolute value of its weight is less than 1% of the absolute value of the maximum weight for a given neuron. I repeat this identification of variable of lesser importance trough all my p neurons.

I then tried to drop variable that weren't important for any neuron with inconsistent results. (sometimes the performance drops, sometimes not) I also tried other thresholds instead of 1%... but lower treshold will rarely highlight enough variables and higher threshold will highlight to many of them.

Any way to make this kind of a posteriori variable selection work ?